# Map datasets from excel and R

Tags: r, database, bioinformatics, bioconductor, protein-database

I am trying to create master data for interaction analysis of proteins, where I am using STRING database from R and external dataset present in excel(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aJisbhWyqUFcx_wIBMxcDtw5fMIE-z5d/view?usp=sharing)

I would greatly appreciate the help on ideas/codes which can be used for such cases.

My attempted code is given below:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
install.packages("STRINGdb")
library(BiocManager)
library("STRINGdb")
string_db <- STRINGdb$new( version="11", species=469008, score_threshold=00, input_directory="")
library(readxl)
p <- read_excel("1.xlsx")
View(p)
p_mapped <- string_db$map( p, "gene", removeUnmappedRows = TRUE )
**Error in tempMatr[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions**
```

Comment: you can check for various joins using dplyr https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Comment: you should ask http://www.biostars.org/ or https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/